# VTKCamera difference between focal point and position

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, vtk

I am using the vtkCamera and would am trying to move it around and make it look at a certain point. For example, if I want to put the camera at position `(x,y,z)` and make it look at `(0,0,0)` for example with gluLookAt in openGL we would set the eye coordinates to `(x,y,z)` and the centre coordinates to `(0,0,0)` and the up vector to `(0,1,0)`.

In vtk however, using the vtkCamera we have three separate methods, namely `setPosition`, `setFocalPoint` and `setViewUp`

my question is what do  `setPositon` and `setFocalPoint` correspond to?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`setPosition` corresponds to eye coordinates. `setFocalPoint` corresponds to where the camera is looking, so `gluLookAt`. It functions the same way as both openGL and DirectX in that sense.

Comment: Thanks very much, how shoudl I set the viewUp? I mean (0,1,0) is the default but I'm sure there's a correct value for viewUp?

Comment: viewUp is just the Up Vector. It can be whatever you want. There is no "correct" value.

Comment: -1:  The focal point is not the point at which the camera is aimed.  It is the point at which all of the rays of a perspective rendering are focused.

Comment: Given the location, L, and the View Plane Normal, VPN or Direction of Projection (DOP) such that VPN = -DOP (preferably normalized length), you should have some constant C such that the FP = X + C * VPN or equivalently, FP = X - C * DOP. You will have to pick C based on your requirements.

Comment: andand: are you certain about the meaning of the focal point? To me it appears to be the location pointed at; it certainly does not appear to be congruent with the location where the rays of the perspective rendering are focused.